# change color on mouse over according to div's color

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm new to Javascript and I cannot figure out what I have to do to change color of the text when an specific element is on screen. 
I am using Bootstrap 3.
 
I want to change color when user hovers in, but I want the color to change according to the element on screen. For instance, if there is a `.something` element visible on screen, the text would change to color X on hover; if there is a `.somethingelse` element visible, the text would change to color Y on hover.

Here is the HTML

```
  <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="navbar-header">
            <a href="#"><img src="images/black.jpg" alt="Logo"></a>
          </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <div class="active" id="navigation-item1"><a href="#">home</a></div>
        <div class="item"><a href="#about">about</a></div>
        <div class="item"><a href="#contact">contact</a></div>
        <div><a href="image1 url"><img  class="image1" src="images/image1.png" alt="image1"></a></div>   
        <div><a href="image2 url"><img  class="image2" src="images/image2.png" alt="image2"></a></div>     
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="first-block" id="first-div">some text goes here</div>  
<div class="second-block" id="second-div">some more text goes here</div>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
.first-block {
    background-color:rgba(86, 96, 156, 255)
}
.navbar .container .navbar-collapse > div > a{
    float:left;
    padding:45px 10px 0px 10px;
    color:white;
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add your comment above.

Comment: How are you trying to change the color of the navbar elements? You have to take a look at the bootstrap CSS to see how the actual color is being applied. It is probably something like `.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a`, so you have to use that selector to override it.

Comment: Thank you very much, @azeós! It helped a lot and I found the solution (edited on my post). Thanks

Comment: Heya, thx for sharing a solution, glad you found one! Please consider editing it *out* of your question and posting it as an *answer* to your own question. Makes it easier for others to spot.

Comment: OK, I'll do it. Thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, here is the answer (thanks to @azeós):

```
 function isScrolledIntoView(elem){
 var docViewTop = $(window).scrollTop();
 var docViewBottom = docViewTop + $(window).height();

 var elemTop = $(elem).offset().top;
 var elemBottom = elemTop + $(elem).height();

 return ((elemBottom >= docViewTop) && (elemTop <= docViewBottom)
 && (elemBottom <= docViewBottom) &&  (elemTop >= docViewTop) );}

$(window).scroll(function () {
       isOnScreen = isScrolledIntoView("#second-div");
       if(isOnScreen){
          $(".navbar .navbar-collapse > ul > li > a.item").mouseenter(function() {
          $(this).css("color", "#9D45DE")
          });
          $(".navbar .navbar-collapse > ul > li > a.item").mouseleave(function() {
          $(this).css("color", "white")
          });          
       }
});
```

Thanks to everybody's help.

Answer (score 0):

I see you joined just for this, so here's the best answer I can think of:


Instead of assigning an HTML element to the div's color, you need to do something along the lines of: `div.style.color = document.getElementById("first-div").style.color;`, assigning the color of the div to the other div's color.


Also, you need to attach event listeners to an element so that the scripts actually trigger in the first place:

```
randomElement.addEventListener("mouseover", changeColorIn);
randomElement.addEventListener("mouseout", changeColorOut);
```

Where `randomElement` is a reference to an HTML element (obtained by `document.getElementById` or such).


Hope I helped!

Comment: Hi. Thanks for you help! I tried what you said, nothing happened. Sure I did something wrong. Now, I have this new code. It checks if element is on screen and, if true, does something. I can make it to change the color of 'p' element, for instance, but it is not what I want. I tried the addEventListener with this new code, nothing happened. I tried ("a:hover") instead of ('p'), but it only changes if the mouse is fixed over the link, not if it hovers. Anyway, thanks very much for your help and your kind answer. All the best

Comment: Hm.  Sorry I couldn't help.  Good luck!